# Wildfly deploy timeout on debug mode

Tags: java, debugging, eclipse-plugin, wildfly

I'm facing an error while trying to deploy my applications, when trying to start WildFly 10.1.0 in debug mode through eclipse's plugin.
I have 4 applications been deploying directly through wildfly's folder, with its .war files, and 3 applications on my workspace, being deployed on eclipse's plugin.

The error is this one.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'add' at address
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@12ac20df for operation {"operation" => "add-deployer-chains","address" => []} at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.SecurityRealmAddHandler$ServiceInstallStepHandler@2b4e1dec for operation {"address" => [("core-service" => "management"),("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm")],"operation" => "add","map-groups-to-roles" => undefined} at address [
("core-service" => "management"),
("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm")
] failed handling operation rollback -- 
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163) [wildfly-ee-10.1.0.Final.jar:10.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:134) [wildfly-ee-10.1.0.Final.jar:10.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88) [wildfly-ee-10.1.0.Final.jar:10.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:124)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:138)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:54) [wildfly-ee-10.1.0.Final.jar:10.1.0.Final]
ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment ".....-.war" was rolled back with no failure message
ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment ".....-.war" was rolled back with no failure message
ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment ".....-.war" was rolled back with no failure message
ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment ".....-.war" was rolled back with no failure message
ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment ".....-.war" was rolled back with no failure message
ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment ".....-.war" was rolled back with no failure message
ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment ".....-.war" was rolled back with no failure message
```

I know its a timeout, but i dont know why and what should i do to solve this.

When i start the server without the debug mode, this doesn't happen.
It starts much faster and i can access my application normally.
I'm the only one on company that have this issue, and no one figure out whats going on.

I'm using a Linux Ubuntu 64-bit.

I leveled up my Wildfly's VM arguments configuration to this:

```
-Xms256m -Xmx1536m
```

I'm using a custom standalone.xml, used for everyone on my company.

This is taking so long and i'm missing most of the time, trying to startup on debug mode.
(Yes, sometimes and somehow it works and i have like 10 minutes developing while wildfly helps me).

I trully need help cause this is unableling me from work...may anyone help me?

Obs.: I changed the war file names, just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for method breakpoints. If you have breakpoints on methods, just remove it.

[image]